# How to switch language keyboard combination?

Tags: keyboard-layout, language-support

I would like to type Hebrew in Ubuntu. I tried downloading the Hebrew language pack and then setting <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd> as my layout-change shortcut in the *Options* section of "Keyboard Layout".

However, when I actually press <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>, nothing happens. How can I switch my keyboard layout to Hebrew?

Comment: When selecting keyboard key combination to change languages, some combinations do not work (both Alt did not work for me). I am using Shift+Ctrl with no problem.

Comment: In Ubutu 18.04 see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030418/how-to-change-text-entry-in-ubuntu-18-04/1030433#1030433

Comment: you can use the WIN+SPACE keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

### Ubuntu 17.10 and newer (GNOME Shell)

From [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030418/how-to-change-text-entry-in-ubuntu-18-04/1030433#1030433): After adding the desired languages (by navigating to Settings -> Regional & Language), you can use the default keyboard shortcut which is <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> ("super" is another name for the Windows key), or you can click on the top bar menu:

[image: screenshot]

### Ubuntu 13.10 to 17.04 (Unity)

As of Ubuntu 13.10, it is now called **Text Entry Settings** instead of **Keyboard Layout**

It can be reached through either of these methods

1. Going through System Settings -> Text Entry
2. Using the App Indicator as shown in the screen-shot below.

[image: App Indicator icon]

### Ubuntu 13.04 and older

Seems you forgot an important step.

1. Download Hebrew language support. You can do this from the *Install/Remove Languages* section of "Language Support".
2. System Settings -> Keyboard Layout -> "+" -> "Hebrew" -> Add
3. System Settings -> Keyboard Layout -> Options -> Keys to Change Layout -> mark [alt]+[shift] (this step is optional, only if you want that custom keyboard shortcut)

An icon like this should appear in the upper-right after step two:

[image: The keyboard indicator]

Comment: I have the same as above, and still cannot change keyboard layout . . .

Comment: I have done this, for some reason I have only a `close` button which is not saving anything. :-\

Comment: This approach solved my problem

Comment: 'super' is the Windows button.

Comment: This does not answer the question `how to change the hotkey`.

Answer (score 34):

To switch keyboard layout on Ubuntu 12.04

1. Go to **System Settings...**
2. Under **Keyboard Layout** - click on **Options...**

   [image]
3. Under **Key(s) to change layout** - choose the combination of keys you would like to use.

   [image]

Comment: When I set the key combination, and then press it, it doesn't do anything. I can however change the layout by my mouse in the applet, that works perfectly.

Comment: This is now only available in gnome-tweaks (tweaks) and it is now in "Keyboard & Mouse" -> "Additional Layout Options" -> "Switching to another layout" section (at least it was like this in 20.04 and now in 22.04)

Answer (score 6):

### In Ubuntu 12.04 LTS,

Goto the *Keyboard Layout Options* window I could select **Key(s) to change layout** and *mark* the binding of my choice. I use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to ***toggle*** the layout from the keyboard itself without having to use mouse cursor to select the required layout from the panel indicator. The same key combo seemed to work to serf through or select between multiple layouts. *(But in Ubuntu 13.10 it wasn't so easy.)*
[image: snap5]

---

### In Ubuntu 13.10,

Goto the *Keyboard* settings window, under *Shortcuts* tab, I select *Typing*. The default for *Switch to next source* is <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> which didn't seem be working for me and so by clicking on it and I assigned a *New Accelerator...*, to change to next ***L***ayout (I used <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>).

(Then I assigned something similar for Switch to previous source *using the same preferred layout*, and then began to test them. **Switching from the preferred layout to the alternate worked but the reverse did not**. Please refer the next step for the fix.)
[image: saucy1]

**The Fix:** After assigning <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for *"Switch to next source"* using my **preferred layout (A)**, I *changed my keyboard layout* to the **alternative layout (B)** and then assigned the combination to *"Switch to previous source"* (for which I used <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>). Then I tested them, and they work fine. (Maybe disabling *"Switch to previous source"* would work too.)

The new accelerators for the key combos that I used looks like this:
[image: saucy2]

I could then switch to layout (A) using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and back to layout (B) using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: If you are looking for this on Ubuntu 22 or later, you may use gnome tweaks tool -> Keyboard & Mouse -> Additional Layout options

Answer (score 4):

I am a totally new to Ubuntu, I just installed it yesterday and I am loving it, but I have encountered the same problem when I was trying to use keyboard shortcuts to switch from Latin to Arabic, but fortunately I found the solution, here is simply what to do:

> System Settings... → Keyboard Layout → (click on "+" to Add new Language layouts) → Options... → (click on) "Key(s) to change layout" → (tick) "Left Alt+Left Shift" → Close

Answer (score 4):

**Ubuntu 20.04**

To define a custom shortcut for switching between keyboard layouts, find *Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Switch to next input source.*

Answer (score 3):

Double-check if you've got this combination already set in compiz-config. Run it by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, then type `ccsm`, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Sometimes, the shortcut is already used by another program, so you can't use it.

Also, please check if it does work using another combination, e.g. <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you forgot to add Hebrew keyboard layout. No matter how many possible languages you may have, you have to add all languages you want to WRITE with in your keyboard settings.

Something like:
3.- Settings -> Keyboard Layout -> + -> Hebrew -> Add

Answer (score 2):

If you installed language support after keyboard installed you may be experiencing no action on selected combinations (like @OndrejCertik reported above).

You should reset keyboard layout defaults in that case by `System Settings -> Keyboard Layouts -> Reset To Defaults` and setup `Key(s) to change layout` again under `Options...` there.

Answer (score 2):

Settings -> Keyboard Layout -> + -> Arabic -> Add