# How can I add other languages and what are equivalent shortcuts for what "alt+shift" and "crtl+shift" does in Windows?

Tags: 11.10, input-language, shortcut-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to switch language keyboard combination?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68127/how-to-switch-language-keyboard-combination)

I want to type Norwegian when I search via Google. When I add Norwegian from "language support" then the language of Ubuntu changes.

Also, there was an option on Windows, "ctr + shift" which switches between align left and right but I cannot find the equivalent shortcut on Linux. (I know how to do these in LibreOffice)

How can I add other languages to Linux and what are equivalent shortcuts for what "alt+shift" and "crtl+shift" does in Windows?

Comment: @j-johan-edwards but I need to know about the steps as well.

Comment: @j-johan-edwards I saw. there are steps as done which i need to know how to do them

Comment: @j-johan-edwards it worked, i did what you posted as answer there. thanks. it was written "downloaded Hebrew package and I was wondering how to download that package and where it is:) should i delete this question?

Comment: No, I'd leave the moderators to mark it a Duplicate. Others will search for the same problem using your words, making this question valuable "guiding post".

Comment: @explorer You can always reword the question to be about hebrew and then just post the steps you did, that way it shows up on searches for people specifically looking for hebrew support.