# How can I switch between keyboard layouts by pressing a keyboard shortcut like on Windows?

Tags: keyboard-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to switch language keyboard combination?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68127/how-to-switch-language-keyboard-combination)

On Windows I am able to switch between keyboard layouts by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. Is there a similar keyboard shortcut in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Go to **System Settings > Keyboard Layout > Layout > Options > Key(s) to change layout**.

You should be able to select one or more key combinations to change your keyboard layout.

On newer Ubuntu versions the default shortcut is <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>.

Comment: This should be marked as answer...

Comment: But you cannot add custom shortcuts for example [Meta/Win]+[Space]. So is it possible to add your own shortcut?

Comment: This does not work on ubuntu...it is System Settings > Text Entry

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: By the way: "super" button is Windows button on keyboard.

Comment: To define a custom shortcut in Ubuntu 20.04, find _Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Switch to next input source_.

Comment: In Ubuntu Mate, you will need to manually select the shortcut inside the `Switching to another layout` submenu (i.e., instead of the `Key(s) to change layout` submenu).

Answer (score 3):

The same. If don't work, choose keyboard layouts and then preferences and keys to switch the layout.

Comment: I didn't manage to set this shortcut in 13.10.