# How to type in two languages?

Tags: locale, input-language

How can I type Persian and English in Ubuntu 12.10?

And how can I switch between these two languages like Windows (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>)?

Comment: Do the Persian language have different characters than English, or it only differs on the structure?

Comment: It seems to me that the answers given to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68127/how-to-switch-language-keyboard-combination?) might help you, once you have installed farsi language support _and_ keyboard layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the Persian Keyboard layout.  Click the + sign to add

[image]

Choose the correct layout that suites you, and then click on Add

[image]

Click on Options to choose the key combination that you want, in your case <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 for having edited the screenshots for readability