# How to navigate through directories named with non-latin characters?

Tags: command-line, bash, directory

I just don't know if it's possible and how to `cd` for example in a dir that **is not** named with latin characters.

Example: `$ cd άλφα` or `$ cd альфа`

Update: In a terminal it is ok, but in a CLI environment not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course it's possible as long as directories with these names exists.

#### The simple way:

[image: terminal]

How I made:

- I ran `ls` command in the parent directory where a directory what is named with non-latin characters.
- With the mouse, I selected the name of the directory (nothing more).
- I typed `cd` followed by a <kbd>Space</kbd> then I pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> and, of course <kbd>Enter</kbd>(again, nothing more).

If you can't use the mouse, see [this quick tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/312215/2353900).

#### The right way:

- Add the new keyboard layouts that you need (greek, russian,...)

  - Go in *System settings* → *Personal* → *Keyboard Layout* and add a new layout:

    [image: add new keyboard layout]
- When you type in terminal, [switch between layouts](https://askubuntu.com/a/145421/147044) to type in what language do you wish.

---

For tty1 (where you can go with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) - and not only - I found another trick:

```
~ $ ls 
bin         Desktop    file.gif  nohup.out  Sent to Ubuntu One  ttyrecord  άλφα
Descărcări  Documente  Muzică    Poze       tmp.txt             Video
~ $ ls > tmp.txt # redirect the output of 'ls' command to 'tmp.txt' file
~ $ cat tmp.txt
bin
Descărcări
Desktop
Documente
file.gif
Muzică
nohup.out
Poze
Sent to Ubuntu One
tmp.txt
ttyrecord
Video
άλφα
~ $ # our directory is on line 13 (in my case); we will use this number in next command
~ $ cat tmp.txt | sed -n 13p
άλφα
~ $ cd $(cat tmp.txt | sed -n 13p)
~/άλφα $ # voila
~/άλφα > rm -v ../tmp.txt
removed ‘../tmp.txt’
~/άλφα $
```

Comment: Radu Radeanu , I have one question about. I made that, but now i dont know how to change the language to use , i need to use two different languages , spanish and russian. Ihave been instaled , but i need an easy way to change each time. thanks

Comment: What about when I use CLI (Alt+Ctrl+[F1-F6]) and not a terminal? Every non-latin named dir appears like "WTF"!

Comment: @NikosGr I mentioned about this in the answer: *If you can't use the mouse, see [this quick tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/a/312215/2353900).*. In my tty, each greek character appear normally.

Comment: But what's the point to use the mouse if after the `$ ls` command every greek named dir appears like chinese? Will it work? (That's happening only when I am in tty1-6)

Comment: @NikosGr See my new edits.

Comment: @NikosGr It should work in both cases even if you see them like chinese characters. Just try it!

Answer (score 1):

The neat thing about files and directories on Linux is that they all have [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) number. For instance, doing `ls -i` gives me in my home folder the following results:

```
6038625 图片/
5809021 搜狐影音/
6038605 文档/
6038600 桌面/
```

Now, what's good about this is that we can use that number to obtain its name via `find` command with its `-inum` flag, and `cd` to any of those folders like so:

```
$ pwd                                                              
/home/xieerqi
$ cd "$(find -maxdepth 1 -type d -inum 6038625)"                   
$ pwd
/home/xieerqi/图片
```

And of course since we did `ls -i` from the current working directory, we only need `-maxdepth 1`. This is actually a very frequent approach to deleting filenames that are problematic or impossible to obtain via copy-paste.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility to avoid having to do that at all: `sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal`

This adds an "Open in Terminal" item to the File menu and the right-click context menu (when no file is selected) in Nautilus. i.e.: Navigate to the offending folder in Nautilus and then File,Open in Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You could use zsh as your default terminal (if you do, I'd suggest getting oh-my-zsh as well for extra goodies).
zsh tab-complete allows you 'scroll' through the contents of a directory by pressing tab.
You can see a what I'm talking about at 0:53 in this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fE3tYK_wUj8