# How to have sub-layouts of a specific keyboard layout in Ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

In Windows it is possible to arrange your keyboard layouts in 2 levels as following:

- **1.** English:

  - **1.1.** English US
  - **1.2.** English UK
- **2.** German

And you are able to:

- **a)** switch directly between **1.** and **2.** using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.
- **b)** switch directly between **1.1.** and **1.2.** using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> (when **1.** is chosen).

How can I arrange the same setup in Ubuntu if is it possible?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many shortcuts to choose to [switch between keyboard layouts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68127/how-to-switch-language-keyboard-combination), but none fits with what you want.

Anyway, it can be done using some tricks.

#### a) Switch directly between English (English US, English UK) and German

First, create the script, let's call it `change_layouts`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

en_layouts="['us', 'gb']"
de_layouts="['de']"

current_layouts=$(gsettings get org.gnome.libgnomekbd.keyboard layouts)

if [ "$current_layouts" = "$en_layouts" ]; then
    gsettings set org.gnome.libgnomekbd.keyboard layouts "$de_layouts"
else 
    gsettings set org.gnome.libgnomekbd.keyboard layouts "$en_layouts"
fi
```

Save the script in your `~/bin` directory and don't forget to make it executable:

```
chmod +x ~/bin/change_layouts
```

Now you can test the script in terminal. Run it more times to see how it works.

Second, add a custom shortcut for this script. Go to **System Setting** → **Keyboard** → **Shortcuts** → **Custom Shortcuts** and follow the instructions from the below image:

[image: add custom shrtcut]

For some reasons, at least in my case, if I set the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> shortcut, this will not run the script. Maybe this is a bug. But there are many other choices, like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.

#### b) Switch directly between English US and English UK (when English is chosen)

Go to **System Setting** → **Keyboard Layout** → **Options** → **Key(s) to change layout** and tick <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>:

[image: Key(s) to change layout]

Related:

- [Advanced keyboard layout options](https://askubuntu.com/q/353994/147044)

Comment: Great! Thank you very very much!

There is still one little glitch that I would like to fix. When there is only one layout (in the `de_layouts`), the icon for displaying the current language disappears. 

I've created a workaround by putting the entry 'de' two times: `['de', 'de']` but it is a bit of an ugly fix. I would be happier if there is a way for the keyboard layout icon not to disappear when it contains only one layout.
And thanks again! :)

Comment: @AntonPetrov The problem is that there is no way for keyboard indicator to be shown if there is only one layout set. This is a part of the design. If you had asked, I would have offered you the same solution: `de_layouts="['de', 'de']"` or maybe `de_layouts="['de', 'de\tnodeadkeys']"`