# I cannot use non-letters keys (czech layout) in any application

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Since I installed Ubuntu (13.04; before that I was using Windows) I haven't been able to use non-letters keys (such as 123[];/.,) in any application. When I was installing Ubuntu I chose Czech layout, but when I switch to US layout it makes no different. I have tried external keyboard (I'm using Lenovo ThinkPad E430), but it doesn't work either. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Are you sure that you switched correctly to US layout? Can you shou us a picture with your layout chart?

Comment: Open a terminal, run the command `xev`, and in the xev window, type a non-letter key. What appears in the terminal (the block of 5 lines starting with “KeyPress event”)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use czech layout, you can type for example `[` as follow:

[image: czech layout chart]

The things goes something like follows. Let's take for example this key:

[image: czech key]

To type `ú` - press <kbd>ú</kbd>.

To type `/` - press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ú</kbd>.

To type `[` - press <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>ú</kbd>.

To type `÷` - press <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ú</kbd>.

Comment: I'm sorry I just partly solved it myself. When I opened keyboard layout settings, the Czech layout was chosen as a primary layout (then it really makes no different which layout I was currently using and it didn't work). But I tried to changed it, so the US layout is the primary one now and it works perfectly. Now I can use non-letters keys in all application, but I cannot have Czech layout set as a default one. Is there some simple fix to this (Czech layout set as a default one and still be able to use non-letters keys)?

Comment: @Tatarkow Yes, follow the instructions from the answer to type ant character do you wish when you use Czech layout.

Comment: I maybe didn't express correctly, when I said in any application I didn't mean for example libre office (I know how to write symbols), I meant application like games or blender, where the keys do something. And the problem is that, if the Czech layout is set as a default layout, those programs won't register if I press the non-letter key or not.

Comment: @Tatarkow Well, the when you will go in a game, you can [switch quickly between keyboard layouts](http://askubuntu.com/a/145421/147044).

Comment: OK, at first I didn't change the layout properly, so there was no way to use those keys, which was a complication, but as I wrote I had discovered that, I hadn't change it properly and if I do, then it works (I still have to change the layout but it's not a big deal). I'm sorry for bothering you (I must look like an idiot now) and thank you.