# How to type the Indian Rupee Symbol?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, special-characters

I want to type the Indian Rupee Symbol. So I went to System Settings >> Keyboard Layout and clicked on the *Options* button. Under the `Adding Currency signs to keys` sections, I checked the `Rupee on 4` option.

[image]

Later when I opened the Layout Chart of the Keyboard there was Rupee sign in the <kbd>4</kbd> key but I do not know how to type the symbol. What combination of the keys will type the Rupee symbol on the screen?

[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just press <kbd>Alt R</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> like in below image:

[image]

See also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/353839/147044).

**Note:** You need to change your keyboard setting to English (India, with rupee sign) as default for this to work.

Comment: I tried it but that method doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @Dineshkumar Are you using *English (US)* keyboard layout? If yes, then this is a problem. Try to change it to *English (India, with RupeeSign)* for example. See also: http://abhidg.wordpress.com/2010/10/14/typing-the-indian-rupee-symbol-in-debianubuntu/.

Comment: I changed the layout to *English (India, with RupeeSign)* and now I can type the Indian Rupee symbol **₹** :) But with this layout, I can type the symbol even without selecting the `Rupee on 4` option. So what is the point of having a separate option for that when it can be done only with a particular layout (even without enabling the option)?

Comment: @Dineshkumar What is the point:  selecting the **Rupee on 4** option will work with any other keyboard layout different by **Englsh (US)**. Maybe is a kind of bug. Some explanations you can find here: http://abhidg.wordpress.com/2010/10/14/typing-the-indian-rupee-symbol-in-debianubuntu/

Comment: @Dineshkumar the problem is that **Rupee on 4** will work with any keyboard with AltGt enabled. English(US) is one of the few layouts that did not enable AltGr. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/432957/alt-gr-key-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-13-10

Comment: For LinuxMint release 17.1 (rebecca), I opened Keyboard -> Layouts tab -> Options -> Adding currency signs to certain keys option -> Check 'Rupee on 4'. Use Alt-R + 4 key to type the rupee symbol.

Answer (score 15):

The other way is to use the following combination on any keyboard 
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> then type `20b9` then <kbd>spacebar</kbd>
This will add the rupee symbol.

Comment: It did not work with  LibreOffice on Ubuntu 14.04.LTS updated till March 2016.

Comment: @bluepearlsky: just tested it . it works just fine. please press the keys in succession. it will work.

Comment: This is the only method that works for me in Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 7):

IN ubuntu 14.04 LTS to get rupee sign (₹) follow the steps

1. click on symbol En
2. select text entry
3. click on <kbd>+</kbd> sign
4. double-click english(India ,with rupee sign)
5. close it
6. again click on symbol En
7. select english(India ,with rupee sign)
8. to type rupee sign press right <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

For using rupee symbol (<kbd>₹</kbd>) go to insert → then symbol → then select rupee symbol → then go to shortcut key → there you put new shortcut key as (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>) → then assign.
After that you may use this symbol by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> from next time.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Your answer is not understandable, please explain what you mean by "go to insert".

Answer (score 2):

**For 16.04 LTS**

It is *right side* ALT + 4 while using English (India, with rupee sign ) keyboard layout.

Simply type " Text Entry " in dash and you will be able to select/add keyboard layouts. This works in 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add English(India, with Rupee sign) layout in Keyboard settings.
2. Select this layout in the applet on the panel.
3. Use <kbd>alt gr</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>, if your keyboard has ₹ symbol on <kbd>4</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating an Homepage and you need
the currency as Indian Rupee, then you need the
charset-iso-code as UTF-8 AS follows in HTML :

I will display Indian Rupee with ₨

8360 is the reserved number in HTML for Indian Rupee.