# Left Alt combinations with xmodmap

Tags: xmodmap

How I can change `Alt`+`symbol` to some other ?

For example,

I changed semi-colon like this:

```
keycode 47   = BackSpace colon semicolon colon semicolon colon
```

But I want `Alt`+; to produce ;.

Comment: Maybe this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/423245/16395 can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that `xmodmap` is sort of deprecated, and will have problems --- for example, [the keyboard is re-set on each layout change](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1318452) (that sometime happens when you didn't even think); the file `~/.Xmodmap` can be loaded or not depending on your Desktop and DM (display manager). You see more detailed info [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/423245/16395) and a more "modern"  way of making the change in [this blog post by myself](http://rlog.rgtti.com/2014/05/01/how-to-modify-a-keyboard-layout-in-linux/).

Nevertheless, if you have just one layout maybe `xmodmap` can work for you, as it seems from your post... so:

1. Find the keycode of your "+" key; for example, in my laptop with US intl keyboard:

   ```
   [:~] % xmodmap -pke | grep plus     
   keycode  21 = equal plus equal plus multiply division
   keycode 126 = plusminus NoSymbol plusminus
   ```

`xmodmap -pke` will dump your full keyboard map, and the `grep` is there to filter just the keys that define "+", which is called "plus" in this case (and I have it on shift-<kbd>=</kbd>).

2. To have a colon on AltGr+<kbd>+</kbd>, you can feed to `xmodmap` the line:

   ```
    keycode  21 = equal plus equal plus semicolon colon
   ```

This will use as a modifier the keys [which is defined as AltGr in your keyboard layout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432957/alt-gr-key-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-13-10). In my keyboard it is the Right-Alt key, but YMMV.

Comment: I am more interested about usual Alt (left one). I want to have every Alt_L combinations to work as usual on the system, except some specified with xmodmap. I will be pretty happy to have solution with another tool. And yes, I am annoyed by reset behavior of xmodmap.

Comment: Normally Alt_L is not a shift --- it is not used to create characters, it is a modifier and normally intercepted by applications. Now, I know it should be possible to define it as you like with the XKB system, but... read the first quote on http://www.charvolant.org/~doug/xkb/html/xkb.html ;-|

Comment: Unfortunately, all documentation I see is useless for the end-use. I cannot find solutions for my problem. I don't have time for experiments. Thank you)).