# Where to put xmodmap command execution for remapping CapsLock to Esc?

Tags: keyboard, vim, xmodmap

I am a vim user and I use <kbd>Esc</kbd> frequently so I mapped <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

I currently have this in my `~/.profile`:

```
# remap Esc to Caps Lock
xmodmap -e 'clear Lock' -e 'keycode 0x42 = Escape'
```

The problem is that every time I suspend my computer or even lock the screen, the mapping of <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> goes back to its default.

My question is, where should I put this line so that the remap remains even after suspension and locking the screen (etc).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that [`xmodmap` is deprecated](http://ebb.org/bkuhn/blog/2011/05/31/x.html), and the keyboard layout is resetted at strange times. See if https://askubuntu.com/a/464618/16395 can help you.

In `gnome-shell` you can achieve this thing by setting, in `gnome-tweak-tool`, one of  these options:

[image: gnome tweak tool screenshot editing caps lock behavior]

You should be able to find an equivalent thing for Elementary.

See also https://askubuntu.com/a/629043/16395 and [Map AltGr-[a..z] and Shift-AltGr-[A..Z] to greek letter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/422650/map-altgr-a-z-and-shift-altgr-a-z-to-greek-letter/423245#423245)

Comment: It would be great to add that the modern analog [to xmodmap is xkb](http://ebb.org/bkuhn/blog/2011/05/31/x.html). I didn't know it.

Comment: @Hi-Angel, I'll add the link. Hower, the problem is still here. On-the-fly use of `xkb` system is complex and saying that it is sparsely documented is an understatment... read the first quote here: http://www.charvolant.org/~doug/xkb/html/xkb.html

Comment: In the end, I find easier to [define my own keyboard](http://rlog.rgtti.com/2014/05/01/how-to-modify-a-keyboard-layout-in-linux/)

Comment: Thanks. I found the option in System Settings -> Keyboard -> Options. Should have done proper research.