# Disabling keys in Ubuntu permanently

Tags: scripts, keyboard, startup

I managed to disable a key by following *[Disable key on keyboard](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=842970)*.

Based on drs305 you can disable it permanently by adding the command to the start application.

And I did a work around:

**scripts.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

xmodmap -e 'keycode 64=' // note that this will disable Atl_L key
```

I checked the *Allow executing file as program* checkbox in the *Properties → *Permission* tab. Then after executing the file the command works well. But after including it in the Startup Applications and restarting the computer it doesn't seem to work.

I purposed to do this to make the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> key permanently disable in start up, but nothing work.

Comment: `xmodmap` is, unfortunately, deprecated. Not a duplicate at all, but maybe http://askubuntu.com/a/423245/16395  or  http://askubuntu.com/a/680850/16395  can help you.