# How do I remap keys in ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard

I already know of Xmodmap, but this won't work for me. I'm using a laptop, and I spilled coffee on the built-in keyboard and ruined it, so I'm now using a usb keyboard. On my laptop's keyboard, there are keys to control volume, but the usb keyboard does not have these buttons. Xmodmap wouldn't work for me because I'd have to physically press the volume keys on my laptop's keyboard to remap keys to them, but I obviously can't do that because that keyboard doesn't work. Does anyone know of a way to remap keys on the usb keyboard to control my volume?

Comment: The problem is that xmodmap is deprecated, and the keyboard layout is resetted at strange times. See if http://askubuntu.com/a/464618/16395 can help you. See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/680840/where-to-put-xmodmap-command-execution-for-remapping-capslock-to-esc http://askubuntu.com/questions/422650/map-altgr-a-z-and-shift-altgr-a-z-to-greek-letter