# Compose key stopped working (Xubuntu 14.04)

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, unicode, compose-key

I'm running Xubuntu 14.04 with an Apple USB QWERTY keyboard. Up until last week, RAlt was working fine as my compose key and Ctr-Shift-U was working for Unicode entry. However, it has stopped working.

Here is the keyboard layout in `/etc/default/keyboard`:

```
XKBMODEL="apple"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="lv3:lalt_switch,compose:ralt"
```

I have "Use system defaults" selected in Settings-->Keyboard-->Layout.

I tried re-running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` but it didn't help.

Is there anything else I can try? I'm not having a lot of fun typing French and German without a compose key at the moment!

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: Just a guess... plain US keyboard has no Alt-Gr definitions in layout, see http://askubuntu.com/a/432985/16395 (although it can be a different thing). Ctrl-Shift-U stopped working for me some time ago, it seems that no one is interested... (small list of international keyboard bugs is here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322)

Comment: Thanks @Rmano. It's a real drag trying to type accents on a QWERTY keyboard in Ubuntu.  I tried switching to `English (international AltGr deadkeys)` but it hasn't helped. I'm not sure if the rest of your answer in the other thread applies to me since I'm on Xubuntu.

Comment: Should work on Xubuntu too. I have a little laptop with it and the redefinition shown in my blog http://rlog.rgtti.com/2014/05/01/how-to-modify-a-keyboard-layout-in-linux/ (I have Caps Lock redefined as Compose) works ok. Mind you, I have a spanish keyboard over there... so YMMV.

Comment: @Rmano: OK, looks like you were right. It magically started working around an hour after I changed it to `English (international AltGr deadkeys`. I had tried rebooting straight after I changed it, of course. Weird. Anyway, if you'd like to add that as an answer I'll mark it as correct. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems to be a mix between two things:

1. the fact that the plain us keyboard has no "strange char" (smile intended) definition, as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/432985/16395), and
2. Probably a manifestation of the [layout random change bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1246272) --- it is not marked as affecting Xubuntu, but giving that affects both Unity a Gnome, you never know...