# AltGr is not working

Tags: 14.04, keyboard-layout

I have a strange problem with my <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key.

My keyboard layout is set to "English (international AltGr dead keys)", but when I press <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> I get a normal "e" instead of an "eacute" (é).

As workaround I added a second keyboard layout "English (Dvorak, international with dead keys)". After switching to the Dvorak layout and then immediately back to the AltGr layout, the combination <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> gives an "eacute" (é).

In an other question someone mentioned running xev, so I did that too.
Here is the output BEFORE the switch:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
root 0x2c3, subw 0x0, time 568919, (-1132,160), root:(130,212),
state 0x10, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
root 0x2c3, subw 0x0, time 570395, (-1132,160), root:(130,212),
state 0x90, keycode 26 (keysym 0x65, e), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (65) "e"
XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (65) "e"
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
root 0x2c3, subw 0x0, time 570530, (-1132,160), root:(130,212),
state 0x90, keycode 26 (keysym 0x65, e), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (65) "e"
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
root 0x2c3, subw 0x0, time 571313, (-1132,160), root:(130,212),
state 0x90, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

output AFTER the switch

```
KeyPress event, serial 49, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
root 0x2c3, subw 0x0, time 662306, (62,149), root:(1324,201),
state 0x10, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 49, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
root 0x2c3, subw 0x0, time 662625, (62,149), root:(1324,201),
state 0x90, keycode 26 (keysym 0xe9, eacute), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 2 bytes: (c3 a9) "é"
XmbLookupString gives 2 bytes: (c3 a9) "é"
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 49, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
root 0x2c3, subw 0x0, time 662769, (62,149), root:(1324,201),
state 0x90, keycode 26 (keysym 0xe9, eacute), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 2 bytes: (c3 a9) "é"
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 49, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
root 0x2c3, subw 0x0, time 664317, (62,149), root:(1324,201),
state 0x90, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I don't know if more info is needed to fix my problem, so please let me know if that's the case.
And if you know how to fix it for me, please let me know.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** / reading again your question I understand that this one maybe is not answering you. I will let this here momentarily and see if it can be of general help.

Anyway, [layout switching](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322) is [so broken](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1246272) that it's not a surprise that it can do anything and its contrary... the second link here bite me a lot of time: even if you change layout, Ubuntu will often default to plain `us` unless you switch it back and forth, that may be your problem here.

I'll try here to give some ideas:

In "[Internaltional Alt-Gr dead key](https://zuttobenkyou.wordpress.com/2011/08/24/xorg-using-the-us-international-altgr-intl-variant-keyboard-layout/)" to have a "è" you have to press <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> and *then* <kbd>e</kbd>.

I don't know if the direct <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> is defined to be anything --- I do not have  the layout handy now.

You should be able to see the current layout in settings / region and language / Input Sources --- select the keyboard and press the small keyboard icon.

[image: keyboard layout]

On each key, the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> variants are the one on the right side. The keyboard shown is a personalized one, so it's different from the standard ones available.

You can find more info on my (mostly silent) blog [here](http://rlog.rgtti.com/2014/05/01/how-to-modify-a-keyboard-layout-in-linux/) and [here](http://rlog.rgtti.com/2015/03/26/a-new-nice-trick-for-the-linux-keyboard-greek-letters/), and if you still have problem, check [Alt-Gr key is not working in Ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432957/alt-gr-key-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-13-10) and he post linked from there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rmano. It didn't help fixing my problem, but it did help me to reread my question and hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: I suspect you are experiencing [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1246272) --- the keyboard tend to go to "plain us" at login and then again sometime, and you need to switch back and forth to have your "Alt-Gr intl US" one. I suspect that the bug is still there because no one know why it happens.