# How to enable Alt-Gr on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, keyboard

On my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop installation, **<kbd>Alt-Gr</kbd>** does not work. So I cannot type characters like **<kbd>{</kbd>, <kbd>}</kbd>, <kbd>~</kbd>, <kbd>|</kbd>** etc. (doing this on my PC where everything works).
I tried various suggestions from multiple Ubuntu wikis, forums, Ubuntu support site: Nothing works.

Most solutions are for older Ubuntu versions, a lot seems to be different on Ubuntu 16.04: There is no **System Preferences** (you can install the app manually, but there are no keyboard settings there), I don't find **Keyboard Layout** anywhere...

This is not a duplicate of [Alt-Gr key is not working in Ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432957/alt-gr-key-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-13-10), Ubuntu 16.04 is different!

Edit: Found the keyboard layout display, and it matches the keyboard (now). But <kbd>Alt-Gr</kbd> combinations don't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alt-Gr key is not working in Ubuntu 13.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/432957/alt-gr-key-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-13-10)

Comment: It's 16.04, there is no 'Region and Language' in Settings (which is called 'System Settings' now).

Comment: Ah! A fellow swiss ubuntu user! :-) I'm using Ubuntu (and other Linux distibutions) with swiss-german layout since some time. I'm pretty confused why your keyboard layout doesn't match. I'm using "Alt Gr" pretty often too. Can you explain in more detail what part of the swiss german layout isn't working right?

Comment: Due to an article I found somewhere else, I just changed the keyboard type to 'generic, 105 keys, intl'. Now the keyboard layout displayed *does* match, but the keys don't.
; instead of ö
' instead of ä
\ instead of $
Alt-Gr combinations don't work at all

Comment: The Keyboard Layout Setting is still there, @Rene.  It's just called `Text Entry` now.

Comment: Next update: Now öä$ as well as éàè! work, now I'm back to the original problem: alt-gr combinations don't work: {}[]~|

Comment: What did you do to have öä$ and éàè! back?

Comment: Removed all 'Input sources to use' except one. Now I only have 'German (Switzerland, eliminate dead keys)'

Comment: I wanna say Thanks, and add: **System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Typing -> Alternate Characters Key** is set to **Disabled** so enable it, and **disable Composer key**, because I found it is set to the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> Key; that's the only way I've found it works.

Answer (score 14):

I discovered in System Settings → *Keyboard* → *Shortcuts* → *Typing* that the *Alternate Characters Key* is set to *Disabled*.

I changed *Disabled* to *Alt-Gr* (right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key) and it works now. No need to change and reconfigure the keyboard type.

Comment: If you wants to set this as part of a script or to do it from the Command Line, you can use this command: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['compose:ralt']"`

Answer (score 6):

It's working now.
Here's all I changed, maybe it helps somebody else:

- Changed the keyboard type to *Generic, 105 keys, intl.*, using the `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` command.
- Removed all *input sources to use* from the list, except one.
- Finally, in **System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Typing**, set *Alternate Characters Key* to *Disabled*.

Comment: Thanks! `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` did the trick for me. Even though I had the `English (US)` `English (intl. with AltGr dead keys)` selected in the Keyboard Settings of this new install of Xubuntu LTS 20.04, `AltGr`+`i` would not print `í` in the terminal. However, this did work for other letters like the accented `é`. It turned out that `AltGr` was not properly activated. There is no GUI menu option for doing so in Xubuntu, whereas `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` will ask for this.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 16.04 Dec 27, 2017

**System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Typing** changed the *compose key* to *Right Alt*

Now I can use the other keys <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>,<kbd>o</kbd>=<kbd>°</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>,<kbd>e</kbd>=<kbd>é</kbd> and so on.

Comment: I think this path is no longer there on 18.04, at least on mine

Answer (score 0):

in KDE, Ubuntu it is in settings:

[image]