# How to disable the default action of the right alt key in gnome

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, 17.10, ubuntu-gnome

In order to type non-english characters like ł, ó, or ź I need to use the right alt key but in Gnome the default action is to drag the current window so I'm looking for a way to disable this behavior.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: BTW, it might help to know which keyboard layout you're using.

Comment: If you're running 16.04 or 17.04, try reading this: [How to enable Alt-Gr on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/779448/301745)

Comment: @wjandrea Thank you, the link was very helpful. I'm running the latest 17.10 version but the solution isn't much different.

Comment: Great! Glad we found a solution!

Comment: Oh, the solution was a bit different. OK, then this isn't a duplicate. We should reopen the question.

Comment: @wjandrea if it isn't much different, it's best to just edit the dupe.

Answer (score 0):

How I solved this:
'Settings' -> 'Devices' -> 'Keyboard' -> 'Windows' -> 'Move Window' and set this to 'Disabled'.
Before it was set to 'Level3 Shift'.