# How to enable AltGr on Ubuntu 18.04 using command line?

Tags: server, keyboard

I run Ubuntu 18.04 Server on ESXi VMWare.

So I did

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

and restarted it.

I need "[]" which I need AltGr for. But I always get 89. No matter what I do: <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there really no solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/q/779448/1103140