# How to turn off right ALT to making: πœ©ß←↓→þðæŋ’ə…„”µ

Tags: keyboard

How to turn off right ALT to making characters like: `π œ © ß ← ↓→ þ ð æ ŋ  ə µ`

Comment: Choose a keyboard layout without AltGr --- it's the reverse of this: https://askubuntu.com/a/432985/16395

Comment: my keyboard->shortcuts_panel->typing has no: alt right alt option

Answer (score 1):

I suppose Compose key produces these symbols. If it isn't defined explicitly in the "Keyboard Preferences", then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd> combo is used by default. So if you occasionally press these keys then symbols printed after that are interpreted as Compose sequence.
Check [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey) for the detailed explanation.

You can use some other key or key combo which is not used often if you have no need of Compose key. Define it in your "Keyboard Preferences". As to me I use <kbd>Menu</kbd> key (which is located to the left of <kbd>RCtrl</kbd>) for Compose.