# Dead keys in emacs with ibus

Tags: 13.10, 14.04, keyboard-layout, emacs, ibus

I've just upgraded to 13.10 and noticed that dead keys are not working anymore in emacs (a keystroke to ' leads emacs to display `<dead-acute> is undefined` instead of waiting to the next key. In addition, use of the compose key leads to `<Multi_key> is undefined` and it is impossible to use keybindings such as `<M-^>`. Other applications work fine as far as I can tell.

A brief search on the internet suggested to `(require 'iso-transl)` to `.emacs`. This solves the first issue, but not the other ones.

Another possible workaround seen on the web is to launch emacs with an empty `XMODIFIERS` variable, as `XMODIFIERS='' emacs`, instead of `XMODIFIERS= @im=ibus` which seems to be the default in 13.10. Then everything works fine, but it looks like a kludge. Is there a way to make emacs work with ibus on this subject?

**Update:**
I observe the same behavior in 14.04.

**Update:** content of `.dmrc` as asked for in comments:

```
[Desktop]
Session=xubuntu
Language=fr_FR
Layout=us       intl
Langlist=fr_FR:en
LCMess=fr_FR.UTF-8
```

Comment: The correct name of the package is `iso-transl` (note the dash.)

Comment: @LarsHaugseth well spotted, thanks. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: I use emacs with AltGr Dead keys and it works fine.

Comment: Which version of emacs do you have?

Comment: @Charo GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.7) of 2014-03-07 on lamiak, modified by Debian. I still have this issue in 14.04, I'll update the question accordingly

Comment: @Virgile: Can you check if you have a file called ~/.dmrc? Can you display its contents?

Comment: @Charo, This is indeed the case. I've put the content in the question, as comments are not really great to format several lines of code.

Comment: Same problems here: fresh 14.04.01, emacs24. I do not want to tweak configuration. it shall run out-of-the-box. I jave problems with "C-c `" to display latex errors.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the things you can try.

Edit the file ~/.dmrc and make sure to set these lines on it:

> ```
> Language=en_US.utf8
> Langlist=en_US:en
> LCMess=en_US.UTF-8
> ```

Edit the file `~/.emacs` and add these lines to it **instead of** `(require 'iso-transl)`:

> ```
> (prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
> (set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)
> (set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
> (set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8)
> (setq default-input-method "latin-1-prefix")
> (defun my-set-default-input-method ()
>   (set-input-method 'latin-1-prefix))
> (add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'my-set-default-input-method)
> ```

You will have to add similar lines to the last one if you use dead keys with other modes in emacs (for instance, `latex-mode`, `tex-mode`, `html-mode`...).

Log out and then log in again.

Even so, if it ever happens to you that dead keys don't work within emacs, try to type `C-\` and see if they work.

**Update:**

If that doesn't work, the only thing that comes to my mind, is that you define two keyboard layouts in your system settings

- English US international dead keys (the one that you have)
- English US

and add a keyboard layout selector in the way explained here:

[How to switch language keyboard combination?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68127/how-to-switch-language-keyboard-combination)

When you work with emacs, choose the "English US" layout. If you have added to your `.emacs` file the lines that I mentioned above, this will force your keyboard to behave as a "dead keys keyboard" within emacs. I know this can be annoying, but it's the only solution to your problem that comes to my mind.

Comment: I have added the lines in question, but this does not change anything. Neither does `C-\`. Thanks for the suggestions anyway.

Comment: Try to change some lines in your  ~/.dmrc file as indicated in my answer.

Comment: But doesn't this mean that my session's language will be English?

Comment: @Virgile: But let's see if in that way the problem disappears. After trying that, you can always come back to your french locale by modifying your ~/.dmrc file again. I have read that [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1472204).

Comment: @Virgile: See the "Update" to my answer.

Comment: Your first suggestion worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 and GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.7)