# how to type in two languages in ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, keyboard-layout

How can I type in Arabic and English languages in Ubuntu 13.10 and switch easily like windows? (using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>)

Comment: Right now there is a bug in Launchpad about this problem. See [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322). Read the description.

Comment: For switching between two keyboard layouts in Ubuntu 13.10, please check if [this link](http://askubuntu.com/a/440612/212123) helps.. comment if you need more help there..

Answer (score 0):

- System Settings... → Keyboard Layout → (click on "+" to Add new Language layouts)
- Options... → (click on) "Key(s) to change layout" → (tick) "Left Alt+Left Shift" → Close

This answer from [How to switch language keyboard combination?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68127/how-to-switch-language-keyboard-combination)

Hope this helps (آمل أن يساعدك هذا)