# setxkbmap incompatible options

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I try to configure my desired keyboard combination using setxkbmap but it seems some options are not compatible, because when I pass my desired options one of them has no affect.

I want both <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Right Shift</kbd> to toggle `Caps Lock`, <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key as <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to switch layouts.

I was not able to have all together working while they work when I try them one by one. Can anybody give me the correct command?

This is the command that I have used:

```
setxkbmap -layout de,us,ir -option "lv3:caps_switch" -option "shift:both_capslock" -option "grp:alt_shift_toggle"
```

Comment: I found that first holding down Shift key and then pressing Alt will work, but normally I press Alt+Shift not vice versa.

Comment: As I told you in [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/403866/147044), see [How to use Alt+Shift to switch keyboard layouts in 13.10?](http://askubuntu.com/q/356357/147044)

Comment: The reason behind using setxkbmap is that it is reliable. I am not affected with mentioned bug in that Q&A and I can switch using keyboard settings. Because of too many keyboard related problems I decided to fall back to setxkbmap which I had used before and works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

To make both <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys together toggle <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> (see the output of `grep 'shift:both_capslock' /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg.lst` command):

```bsh
setxkbmap -option shift:both_capslock
```

To switch <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>:

```bsh
xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Alt_R Meta_R Alt_R Meta_R"
```

To switch layout using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> keyboard shortcut, see the following post if you are using Ubuntu 13.10:

- [How to use Alt+Shift to switch keyboard layouts?](https://askubuntu.com/q/356357/147044)

For Ubuntu 13.04 and older see:

- [How to switch language keyboard combination?](https://askubuntu.com/q/68127/147044)

Comment: Thanks Radu, but what I need is to set pressing both shift keys together to act as caps lock while the other options work as well. With setxkbmap this can be realized by -option "shift:both_capslock".

Comment: @MahdiSadeghi You  wasn't so clear in this sense... I just updated my answer.