# Which US international keyboard layout gives me all umlauts and sharp S?

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, keyboard-layout

I would like to use a US keyboard layout. However, from time to time I need to type German umlauts and sharp S.

All the US international keyboard layouts have left me unsatisfied. I am always either missing sharp S or a way to type the umlauts.

Does anyone have a configuration where they are able to use both sharp S and all umlauts with a US international keyboard layout? If so, would you share how you achieved this?

Comment: You could either [reassign keys](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys) or [switch between keyboard inputs](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68127/how-to-switch-language-keyboard-combination). You can switch between any secondary layout with the shortcut Ctrl+Space.

Comment: @Tim Thanks, I have thought about this approach but my understanding was that international layouts were created exactly to avoid both switching and having to extend some layout manually. Ideally, I would like an out-of-the-box layout which I can then also use on other machines.

Answer (score 2):

I use a regular US keyboard layout, but for all extended characters I mapped the print screen key or the right Windows/Super key to be the compose key. So now when I need a ç I type <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> followed by the <kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>,</kbd> keys. Similarly for characters like ß (<kbd>PrtSc</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>) or © (<kbd>PrtSc</kbd><kbd>O</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>).

See [the Wikipedia entry on the compose key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key) for more information. To set the Compose key (in Gnome), you can try Settings → keyboard → Shortcuts tab → compose key option, but that doesn't list the <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> key I want, so I did the following:

1. Install dconf-editor: `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`
2. Open dconf-editor and go to org → gnome → desktop → input-sources and change xkb-options to `['compose:prsc']`

Answer (score 2):

I found two good ways to do it in Ubuntu.

### [1] altgr-intl Layout

First one is to put this into the terminal or if you want it permanent into the .bashrc file:
`setxkbmap -rules evdev -model evdev -layout us -variant altgr-intl`

Afterwards when clicking the `right-alt-key`/`altgr-key` the whole keyboard changes into phoentics. Here are the important ones:

- `altgr+q` = `ä`, `altg+Q` = `Ä`
- `altgr+p` = `ö`, `altgr+P` = `Ö`
- `altgr+y` = `ü`, `altgr+Y` = `Ü`
- `altgr+s` = `ß`

Press buttons at the same time.

Problems:

- there seems to be only one ß (no ẞ)
- might not work, when altgr button is set to be the compose button
- need to learn shortcuts

### [2] Set a compose button

A second way is to set a compose button.
Install Ubuntu Tweaks `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks` and start it. Click on `Keyboard and Mouse` and on `Compose Key`. Activate it and select a button you like, for example `right-alt`.
Now you can do:

- `compose key` + `"` + `a` = `ä`
- `compose key` + `"` + `A` = `Ä`
- `compose key` + `"` + `u` = `ü`
- `compose key` + `"` + `U` = `Ü`
- `compose key` + `"` + `o` = `ö`
- `compose key` + `"` + `O` = `Ö`
- `compose key` + `ss` = `ß`
- `compose key` + `SS` = `ẞ`

Press buttons after each other.

Problems:

- more clicks, slower

Answer (score 1):

Use the *English (US, international AltGr Unicode combining)* option. This enables the AltGr (right alt key) to act as an option to access more characters.

Answer (score 0):

I have a thinkpad US keyboard that I want to use german Umlauts on (äöüß€).

Here is how to do that in Ubuntu and Debian:

1. run `xev` to determine which "keycode" is the right side alt key
2. Paste this into `~/.Xmodmap` file:

```
! Map umlauts to PRINT SCREEN + 
keycode 135 = Mode_switch
keysym e = e E EuroSign
keysym a = a A adiaeresis Adiaeresis
keysym o = o O odiaeresis Odiaeresis
keysym u = u U udiaeresis Udiaeresis
keysym s = s S ssharp
```

3. add this to your `~/.bashrc`: xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
4. run `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` (or just open a new shell to load your bashrc)

works like a charm :)))

A detailed description can be found [in this blogpost](https://www.blunix.com/blog/using-german-umlauts-on-us-layout-keyboards.html). There is also a table with all the keycodes for more special characters.