# add new language to input source list

Tags: language-support

How to add a new custom entry to Text entry-choose an custom input source list? Note : I want to use a Tamil language keyboard layout 'ta-balini.mim'.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. This link may help though. http://askubuntu.com/questions/68127/how-to-switch-language-keyboard-combination

Answer (score 0):

I hope this link will help you:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions

Answer (score 0):

You install the appropriate package(s), log out and log in again. For Tamil I think installing *ibus-m17n* may be what you want.

Reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html

Comment: Hmm.. I see that I may have misread the question. The answer provided by muzaffar habibullayev is probably more on the spot.