# Keyboard shortcut in Ubuntu 17.10 doesn't exist

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

After an upgrade to 17.10 messed up my keyboard settings, I can’t seem to change them or configure them how I want.

I  go to ‘Region & Language’ and in that section, is a button for input sources.  It shows :”Alternative switch to next source Right Shift.  You can change these shortcuts in the keyboard settings.   But, when you go to the keyboard settings, there is nothing about alternative switch to next source OR Right Shift.   There is no listing or mention of 'Right Shift' and the corresponding keyboard shortcut.  I use the right shift key a lot and now I cannot use it.

Ubuntu 12.04 looked intuitive for these settings and now it looks overly complicated in 17.10

[How to switch language keyboard combination?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68127/how-to-switch-language-keyboard-combination?newreg=14971a53295f4d988f442f15a025558f)

Can anyone help?  I cannot use the right shift key as before since the only function it has now is changing the language input.

Comment: You should find or report bug to [launchpad](http://bugs.launchpad.net) with `apport-bug gnome-settings-daemon`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to install the `gnome-tweak-tool` package. Then you can search for and open *Tweaks* via the *Activities* overview.
You'll find the options for alternative switching shortcuts in *Keyboard & Mouse -> Additional Layout Options -> Switching to another layout*.

Otherwise, this is a command line way to get rid of the "Alternative switch to next source" setting, and with that make your <kbd>Right Shift</kbd> key work as expected:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71997/discussion-on-answer-by-gunnar-hjalmarsson-keyboard-shortcut-in-ubuntu-17-10-doe).