# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS Problem with keyboard shorcut

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

When I was in the upgrading process I had a question about taking a shortcut for changing language input sources (like en, fr, gr, etc) and I typed "control+shift" but now I can see that I need that shortcut for other stuff and I would like to change.

```
Settings -> Keyboard -> Custom Shortcuts (don't work).
```

Tried with this command but I didn't find shortcut (control+shift):

```
gsettings list-recursively | awk '/hotkey/||/keybinding/||/media-key/' | grep Control
```

Comment: Find out solution to reset all shortcuts 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/997989/keyboard-shortcut-in-ubuntu-17-10-doesnt-exist

But it would be nice to someone explain me how to change just this specific shorcut.

Answer (score 0):

Install Gnome Tweaks. Then you can access the option under "Additional Layout Options" on the "Keyboard & Mouse" tab.