# How to change text entry in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support, 18.04, text

I was using Ubuntu 16.04. There it was so easy to change the text entry option. **Settings** > **Text entry**.

But when I switch to Ubuntu 18.04 I can't find such option. So how can I write in another language? How to change text entry i.e. by <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> or something like that?

Comment: If you need something like `<Ctrl+Shift>` or `<Alt+Shift>` you can use GNOME Tweaks (see [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1029605/66509)).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### How to add and select a language in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Edited to make it easier to find *your* language. Thanks to @Gunnar Hjalmarsson.

- Click near the top right corner, select the 'tools' symbol

  [image]
- You arrive at the Settings menu. Select Region & Language
- Click on the long button <kbd>Manage Installed Languages</kbd>

  If the system is new, a window may pop up: 'The language support is not installed completely'. In that case click on <kbd>Install</kbd>
- Click on <kbd>Install/Remove Languages</kbd>

  [image]
- **Select and tick *your* language(s)**, like I did with Swedish

  [image]
- Click on <kbd>Apply</kbd>
- Now you might want to select language for menus and windows and drag it to the top of the box

  [image]

  It should look like this with your language at the top of the box

  [image]
- Now you might want to click on <kbd>Apply System-Wide</kbd>
- Close the window 'Language support' and the Settings menu
- Click near the top right corner, select the 'tools' symbol to restart the Settings menu
- Back in the Settings menu, Click on **<kbd>+</kbd>**
- Mark 'your language' (that you should find directly without clicking on `⋮`)

  [image]
- Click on the green button <kbd>Add</kbd>

---

> - If you do not find your language directly
>
>   - Click on `⋮`
>
>     [image: screenshot-click on <code>**⋮**</code>]
>
>     to get a list with more languages.
>   - Click on 'Other' (it might be slow, so wait a while ...)
>   - Select *your* language from the long list
>
>     [image]
>   - Click on the green button <kbd>Add</kbd>

---

- Mark your language in the list

  [image]
- Click on **<kbd>^</kbd>** to move it to the top of the list
- Now you can select between English and your language. Click on the applet near the top right corner of the screen.

  [image]

### How to assign a keyboard shortcut to switch keyboard layout

The default shortcuts for keyboard layout switching are <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. @N0rbert suggested to add a screenshot with assigning of keyboard shortcut to keyboard layout switching. It is a good idea, and there is a detailed description at this link,

[18.04 ctrl+shift to change language](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029588/18-04-ctrlshift-to-change-language/1029605#1029605)

> - On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with GNOME desktop from GNOME Tweaks.
>
>   1. Install it
>
>      ```
>      sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks
>      ```
>   2. Then open GNOME Tweaks (`gnome-tweaks`).
>   3. Select *Keyboard & Mouse* tab
>   4. Click *Additional Layout Options* button
>   5. Expand *Switching to another layout*
>   6. Select <kbd>Ctrl+Shift</kbd> here

[image]

Right-click and open the screenshot picture in another [big] window to see it in full size. That way it is easier to read the text.

Comment: Could you please add screenshot with assigning of keyboard shortcut to keyboard layout switching.

Comment: @N0rbert, Done :-) Good idea (and +1 to your answer in that other thread).

Comment: I did all this and I can't write polish diacritics anywhere. Right Alt+ letter just desn't work

Comment: @zwolin, I have no experience of Polish. Let us hope that someone who knows will chip in and help you. Maybe chances are better, if you create an own question and describe your particular case with as many details as possible.

Comment: I found a solution for my case - in GNOME Tweaks I set Keyboard & Mouse->Additional Layout Options -> Key to choose the 3rd level -> Right Alt. Now Polish diacritic characters work as expected

Comment: @zwolin, Congratulations and thanks for sharing your solution :-)