# Change which language you use

Tags: language-support

language are not listed and not click … at the bottom

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change text entry in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030418/how-to-change-text-entry-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: @sudodus: The question appears to be about display languages, not input sources.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Yes, but I think it will be answered implicitly in the link that I suggested. Please answer, if you have a more direct way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

To get more language options to choose between, click the *Manage Installed Languages* button and install more languages.

The ... at the bottom was deliberately hidden in Ubuntu 18.04, since you currently can't successfully select other languages but the installed ones anyway. That may be changed in future releases.

Comment: +1. Thanks for this 'direct solution'. I was really doing this the hard way. (It is obvious that I don't know yet how to navigate in gnome :-P ) I will try to simplify my answer in that other thread according to your solution.

Comment: @sudodus: This is a delta compared to vanilla GNOME. To a large extent it's due to the use of language packs in Ubuntu.