# Changing language when typing the password

Tags: password, language-support

I was making some changes to the system language and keyboard input language and I was asked to restart to apply the changes. When it had restarted, I tried to type my password and it was always incorrect. Then I discovered that I was typing my password in Arabic but my password is in English.

The question here: How can I change the keyboard language when I am typing the password?

Answer (score 0):

**option 1:**

In the bar at the top of your screen, you should see a small box (probably white with a letter in it) select that and you should get a drop down for language selection. Select English.

**option 2:**

you may have a small circle with a man in it in the top bar. If so select that and select onscreen keyboard.

**option 3:**

Boot into safe mode and set the language in there to English and then reboot.

**option 4:**

Reset password in safe mode
[How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

---

After you login you should set up a keyboard shortcut to change the language of your keyboard [How to switch language keyboard combination?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68127/how-to-switch-language-keyboard-combination)