# Switching to other Language without actually called/clicked keys/options in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: language-support

Why Ubuntu 18.04 mistakenly switch to other language in language banner, without actually prompt to do by keyboard command  or mouse click?

Comment: Hard to tell from the description. Can you associate *any* action to the layout switching (e.g. certain key press, mouse click/scroll at certain spots, opening certain application(s) etc.)?

Comment: I haven't switched anything, it just get changed while typing in middle

Comment: Any particular key-press?

Comment: No specific Keypress... It comes (I only used A-Z and 0-9 not shift/alt/ctrl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because, the default setting for switching language set by " `_` + `Shift` + `KeyPress`", Change the setting something similar to this

[How to switch language keyboard combination?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68127/how-to-switch-language-keyboard-combination?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)