# How to switch keyboard layout using the command line

Tags: keyboard-layout

The present question does not concern how to use keyboard shortcuts to navigate through a list of layouts, but how to script this with bash commands.

In a script I wrote to create a file where each line contains the first and the last word of each page of my greek dictionary, I use "setxkbmap -layout gr,… -variant polytonic,…" to have my polytonic greek layout automatically activated.

Unfortunately, in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, this command resets the list of available layouts without resetting accordingly the list which the graphical interface relies on to operate. This situation makes the graphical interface unfunctional.

When the script terminates, neither the graphical interface nor the keyboard shortcuts can be used to revert to the initial situation. As the greek layout does not include any latin character, no bash command can be typed in.

So my question is : is it possible, and how to do it, to activate any layout in the list of available layouts, without modifying the list created by the graphical interface ?
In other words, how to activate a layout without using «setxkbmap» ? Or which option of «setxkbmap» does perform such activation ?

Arbiel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to switch language keyboard combination?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68127/how-to-switch-language-keyboard-combination)

Comment: Hi..So for example you have us n gr layouts.. You want to change the layout to gr. Or something else?

Comment: Some contributors suggest my question is a duplicate of  "How to switch language keyboard combination" This is not the case as my question concerns using the command line, and not the graphical interface or keyboard shortcuts.