# How could I stop using left Ctrl as a way to switch language?

Tags: shortcuts

When I update Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, I am asked to choose a shortcut for switching language and I choose left Ctrl. However, now I don't like it and want to change it back. However, why can't I find how to replace it in Settings?

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tSuW.png)
Here, the way of left Ctrl is showed, but I can not find it in shortcut settings:
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEm6s.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to switch language keyboard combination?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68127/how-to-switch-language-keyboard-combination)