# Keyboard layout input sources is not being remembered when system restarted after Ubuntu Budgie upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: upgrade, keyboard-layout, input

After Ubuntu Budgie system upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 the correct system keyboard (in my case Bulgarian traditional phonetic - 'асдф') did not work but the layout was replaced by English (US) - 'asdf' despite it indicates Bulgarian. When Bulgarian input source is removed and added again the characters display correctly ('асдф') until the next logging out and in when again English (US) displaces Bulgarian layout.

I am using English (US) as default layout.

I tried to see if I can see any message appearing when run settings from terminal using 'gnome-control-center' but nothing.
fcitx Is not installed.

And one more thing you may ask about:

```
cat /etc/default/keyboard
XKBLAYOUT="us,bg"
XKBVARIANT=",phonetic"
BACKSPACE="guess"
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBOPTIONS="grp:lctrl_lshift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` this makes system remember what you select, I hope.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Sadaharu Wakisaka! This but it didn't work. I also run 'sudo gnome-control-center', but it still behaves as before.

Comment: `sudo` is a command that the program open as a root user.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the default keyboard layout is one.

```
cat /etc/default/keyboard

XKBLAYOUT="bg"
XKBVARIANT="phonetic"
BACKSPACE="guess"
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBOPTIONS="grp:lctrl_lshift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
```

If you think the keyboard is actually Bulgarian layout.
And you can pretend whatever the layout is on your keyboard, add an extra layout.

Then Shortcut key like <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> would switch between layouts.

Comment: It looks like there is another settings file as I don't change the the keyboard layout by using 'Control' + 'Space', but 'Win" + 'Space'.  

Furthermore:     

cat /etc/default/keyboard       // displays:

XKBLAYOUT="us,bg"   

XKBVARIANT=",phonetic"   

BACKSPACE="guess"   

XKBMODEL="pc105"   

XKBOPTIONS="grp:lctrl_lshift_toggle,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,grp_led:scroll"

Comment: Like ctrl+spc means including super+spc. I hope you get the point.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. 
For some reason super+spc changes the keyboard layout from US to BG and from BG to US here (again only i setup the layout settings) , but ctrl+spc does nothing no matter what /etc/default/keyboard says. That's why I think these settings might have been stored somewhere else and modifying /etc/default/keyboard does nothing.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/68127/how-to-switch-language-keyboard-combination It used to be ctl+spc 10 years ago, super+spc is messing with app launcher, I like ctl+spc. You can read other pages.

Comment: After too long I found that both ibus and fcitx were installed and after removing ibus: "sudo apt remove ibus" the system started working properly. Thank you Sadaharu Wakisaka for your help!