# Ubuntu 22.04 keyboard language layout toggle

Tags: updates, keyboard, shortcut-keys, 22.04, keyboard-layout

I've just updated to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS version and my keyboard behavior changed after that.

During the update process I was asked to choose "[Method for toggling between national and Latin mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usl6E.png)" and i chose left Alt.

Now I want to disable this toggle because all my keyboard shortcuts with left Alt key not working anymore, how can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to switch language keyboard combination?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68127/how-to-switch-language-keyboard-combination)

Comment: No, my input source change shortcut is set to `Super + Space` and the left Alt key is doing the same. I want to switch input sources with `Super + Space` only and disable this switch for the left Alt key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset your xkb options using the command:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
```

This will disable left Alt toggling the keyboard layout.

If desired, you can change keyboard options with "Tweaks" (not installed by default), "Keyboard & Mouse" tab, button "Additional Layout Options".

Comment: Thanks! Now keyboard shortcuts working as expected